# DataGrid игнорирует добавление столбцов

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="c_dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding myDT.DefaultView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                              CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                              CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                              CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False"
                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden".>
```

Изначально, мы привязывает к ней `DataTable`: `public DataTable myDT { get; set; }`. Если мы изменяем, например, заголовок столбца через `DataTable`, то он изменяется и на форме, но если мы добавляем новый столбец в `DataTable`, например вот так: `dataTable.Columns.Add("NewRowName", typeof(string), "");`
или вот так:

```
dataTable.Columns.Add("NewRowName");
foreach (DataRow dataTableRow in dataTable.Rows) {
    dataTableRow["NewRowName"] = "";
}
```

То ничего не происходит, в `DataTable` столбец добавился, а на форму - нет.

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если честно, то не знаю, почему это работает, возможно криво работает INotifyPropertyChanged внутри DataTable, но обнуление коллекции исправило мою проблему.

Создаем событие для оповещения об изменении коллекции:

```
public delegate void DataTableUpdated(DataTable dt);
public event DataTableUpdated DataTableUpdate;
```

В кострукторе VM подписываемся на событие:

```
DataTableUpdate += dt => {
                          myDT = null;
                          myDT = dt;
                         };
```

Вполне возможно, что это не самый лучший вариант.